# using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end with 2 different objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use 2 different objects for ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end.

for example:

```
             <tr ng-repeat-start="file in files">
                <td class="name-col">{{file.name}}<br>
                </td>
                <td class="name-col">{{file.progress}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat-end="otherFile in otherFiles">
                <td colspan="2">
                  {{otherFile.errors}}
                </td>
              </tr>
```

Doesn't seem to work right now and it only assumes the first object (files)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `ng-repeat-end` does not accept an argument. 
If you want to `ng-repeat` over a different object like you have above, you would need to start a new `ng-repeat` block.

Edit: Added wrapping html to show a point. You might want to change things around a bit.

```
   <div ng-repeat="file in files track by $index">
    <tr>
        <td class="name-col">{{file.name}}<br>
        </td>
        <td class="name-col">{{file.progress}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          {{otherFile[$index].errors}}
        </td>
      </tr>
   </div>
```

Comment: how would otherFile know to iterate over otherFiles in this case?

Comment: You will have to get creative with how you want to handle the html, but look a the edit I made to my post and I think you can get the gist.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would do:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="file in files">
            <td class="name-col">{{file.name}}<br>
            </td>
            <td class="name-col">{{file.progress}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat-end>
            <td colspan="2">
              {{otherFiles[ $index ].errors}}
            </td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: @jeremy it isn't working? Or it isn't the way you want?